# Video Inside Silhouette using kinect

Tags: processing, kinect, interaction

I am using this [git](https://github.com/jcbatista/KinectSilhouetteVideoOverlay) 
I am getting **error data/config.json does not exist or could not be read**. 
How do I create json file or load one?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration json file is missing from the source code, however, checking out how the json is parsed in [ConfigManager](https://github.com/jcbatista/KinectSilhouetteVideoOverlay/blob/45428c5b94e81dc64c632f568830fb49c6aa8bac/ConfigManager.pde) should allow you to create one from scratch.

Just looking at what the property names and types are in that class you can work out something like this:

```
{
  "clips":[
      {
        "silhouette":"add your silhouette filename here",
        "background":"add your background filename here",
        "duration":0
      }
    ],
    "useKinect":true,
    "useGpu":false,
    "name":"Your Application Name here",
    "resizeSilhouette":false,
    "mirrorSilhouette":false,
    "resizeSilouhette":false,
    "overlayVideo":true,
    "useActionClips":false,
    "silhouettePadding":{
      "top":5,
      "right":5,
      "bottom":5,
      "left":5
    },
    "centerOfMass":true,
    "showTime":true,
    "smoothSilhouette":0,
    "crossfade":0,
    "silhouetteCache":{
      "enabled":false,
      "minFrames":3,
      "maxFrames":10
    },
    "scale":{
      "width":640,
      "height":480
    },
    "osc":{
      "enabled":false,
      "serverPort":12000,
      "clientAddress":"127.0.0.1",
      "clientPort":12001,
      "channels":0
    },
    "actions":{
      "frequency":1,
      "clips":[
        "clipName1","clipName2"
      ]
    }
}
```

If you save this as config.json in your sketch's data folder it should load. 
However, bare in mind this may also crash as I've just placed some dummy placeholder data to give you an idea. Fill in the data you think you know what it should be for your project and figure out the rest as you go along.
Unfortunately the github project you decided to use isn't documented, so this means you will have to go through all the source code and understand it before you get to use it.

Comment: thankyou. Still I am getting an error JSONOblect["clips'] not found.

Comment: I've updated the json config above, turns out there are two clips objects in the config: one at the root and one as part of "actions" which is what was causing the error. Use the updated config above, but be warned you need to place actual paths to video for clipName1, clipName2, etc. Basically this has the properties you need to use, but not the values you need so you need to go through them one by one and configure them for your project. Might worth getting in touch with the repository author and hope he can supply some form of documentation/hints...

Comment: ...otherwise you need to understand all the code yourself.